# Javascript: Run "document.write" in createElement script failed

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with `document.write`. Now, I have a page to load script dynamically. So, I use `document.createElement` to create a `<script>`. And in the javascript file, I use `document.write` to create a `dom` or `iframe` element. But it does not work in every browser. Why not?

Code in homepage:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', 'http://yoururl/test.js');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Code in script test.js:

```
(function(){document.write('hello');})();
```

Comment: What does "dose not work" mean? How does it fail? Does it crash your computer, or does nothing get written, or does something get written 50% of the time, or does it get written in IE6 but not IE 5.5 Mac, or...? Some more description would be very helpful here.

Comment: [document.write](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/apis-in-html-documents.html#document.write) is covered in the draft HTML5 specification. It should not be used after the document has finished loading. There is also no need to wrap it in an immediately executing fucntion expression (doing so isn't harmful, just pointless).

Answer (score 4):

Any document.write statement that runs after the page finishes loading will create a new page and overwrite all of the content of the current page. This is almost certainly not what you intend to have happen.

http://javascript.about.com/library/blwrite.htm

If you want to create a dom element, do it this way and append it to the document (or element):

```
var elem = document.createElement('iframe');
elem.src = "http://www.google.com";
document.getElementById('myContainer').appendChild(elem);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement

Comment: Thx for your help, but my question dose not happen after page load. Before the window.onload, the document.write dose not work. But thank you all the same.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the new script element in the *head*. Content in the *head* is not displayed, so even if the *document.write* call is succeeding, you won't see the text.

If you want content to be displayed, you have to add it to the body (as a child or other descendant) so move the script to the body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<title>Document.write test</title>
<body>
  <div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'http://yoururl/test.js';
      document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(script);
    </script>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

Note that you must still have a valid document after the *document.write* is finished.

The above does not work in Firefox 5, but does in IE 6. Note the warning about [*document.write*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/apis-in-html-documents.html#document.write) in the HTML5 spec:

> This method has very idiosyncratic behavior. In some cases, this method can affect the state of the the HTML parser while the parser is
>   running, resulting in a DOM that does
>   not correspond to the source of the
>   document. In other cases, the call can
>   clear the current page first, as if
>   document.open() had been called. In
>   yet more cases, the method is simply
>   ignored, or throws an exception. To
>   make matters worse, the exact behavior
>   of this method can in some cases be
>   dependent on network latency, which
>   can lead to failures that are very
>   hard to debug. For all these reasons,
>   use of this method is strongly
>   discouraged.**