# How to add and remove js files dynamically

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I have a web page index.php, I want to add and remove JS files to this page dynamically

So far I did,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="" id="dynamic_files"></script>
```

I had planned to change the src of this script tag by

```
function loadJsfiles( filename ){ 
    var filePath = 'include/js/'+filename;
    $("script#dynamic_files").attr('src',filePath);
};
```

and the included js file has script tags in it:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="include/js/profile1.js"></script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="include/js/profile2.js"></script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="include/js/profile3.js"></script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="include/js/profile4.js"></script>'); –
```

My question is that,

will that script tag printed in to my document page, if so how do I remove it

Reference: [Dynamic js files](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml)

Comment: Why not just try it yourself?

Comment: *and the included js file has script tags in it,* Well, it shouldn't have `<script>` tags in an included script file. Leave 'em out.

Comment: @Jared Farrish my planning is to add js files for some events, ie: profile view, edit view, etc and the js files will have to print perticular files in to my webpage

Comment: @xdazz i tried but the src looks same by viewing the source

Comment: Within your `script.js` files to be included, do you have `<script>` tags in them like markup?

Comment: @JaredFarrish like document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="include/js/profile1.js"></script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="include/js/profile2.js"></script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="include/js/profile3.js"></script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="include/js/profile4.js"></script>');

Comment: You CANNOT do document.write after load

Look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530199/javascript-run-document-write-in-createelement-script-failed

Comment: Ok, what you're doing with that code is considered obsolete, and that JavascriptKit site is filled with a lot of approaches and code techniques that should, these days, be avoided. For instance, `document.write()` is hardly *ever* (if ever) used in modern Javascripting, due to it's serious limitations. You seem to indicate you're using jQuery; I would encourage you to look into MooTools, maybe, or Backbone.js as platforms to build your system on. But for your own sake, don't follow through with what you're describing.

Comment: Jared, the code in the link seems ok. It is using DOM and document.createElement. It does not contain document.write, but the OP's code does

Comment: @mplungjan - When I first got started with JS, back in 2002, JavascriptKit was around and it wasn't all that great. In the intervening years, I can't say my impression has improved. Some sites, like QuirksMode, continue to be purveyors of quality, I just have never included that site in that tier, and I would almost guarantee they've got a lot of legacy code hanging around. There's better outlets to learn, like MDN and Javascript Garden. Just my opinion.

Comment: I agree, in this case, however, they were not suggesting document.write but the correct document.createElement and the page in question does not seem obsolete. I have a stronger opinion about w3schools by the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CANNOT do document.write after load

Look here:

[Javascript: Run "document.write" in createElement script failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530199/javascript-run-document-write-in-createelement-script-failed)

You will notice your page will be wiped.

It does not matter which method you use to insert scripts, you need to either stop them from using document.write OR replace the document.write with a custom method.

Perhaps you want to use something like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) - which is a javascript loader (thanks Jared for a better link than
https://developers.google.com/loader/ )

Comment: There's also [Require.JS](http://requirejs.org/), which [works with jQuery](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html).

Comment: [jQuery EasyUI](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/index.php) might pair well with Require.JS and provide a more advanced system to work within than what's being proposed. It appears to be simpler to use than ExtJS, but pretty powerful.

Comment: @JaredFarrish mplungjan i'm using bennadal's corMVC as my platform, what's your opinion about that??

Comment: @user1400191 - It's site looks a little sparse (is it new?). I don't know anything about it. I like [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) as a JS MVC system. [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) is another very interesting entry, an MVVC.

Comment: @user1400191 - Here's an overview of [Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) with Knockout and RequireJS](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/amd-loading.html). Interesting article.

Answer (score 0):

The better example is google analytics

```
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Comment: that link does the same as the code in the site posted by the OP. It is the document.write in the OPs OTHER js file that is the problem

Comment: @Alejo JM Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

```
var dynScript,dynParent;

function createjsfile(filename) {
    var fileref = document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename + "?noxhr="+(new Date()).getTime());
    return fileref;
}

function loadjsfile(filename){
    dynScript = createjsfile(filename);
    dynParent = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    dynParent.appendChild(dynScript);
}

function replacejsfile(filename) {
    var newelement = createjsfile(filename);
    dynParent.replaceChild(newelement, dynScript);
    dynScript = newelement;
}
```

On `body.load` event I do `loadjsfile("script.js")`

and when I want to reload it `replacejsfile("script.js")`